# Memcache.exe failed to install service or service already installed

Tags: php, windows, memcached

I installed xampp on my local computer. The data in the project is stored in memory, but the memcached function did not work on my local machine.

```
$memcache=memcache_connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);
```

Error code:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function memcache_connect() in
```

I called the error, but the solutions didn't work for me.

Suggested solutions include the addition of new services

I am getting this error when adding new service
"failed to install service or service already installed"

```
**Windows 7
**Xampp
**Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/5.6.38
```

Comment: It seems like php cant find the function memcache_connect. Can you post what code you have tried?

Comment: php.ini file
extension=php_memcache.dll
[Memcache]
memcache.allow_failover = 1
memcache.max_failover_attempts=20
memcache.chunk_size =8192
memcache.default_port = 11211

Comment: added php_memcached.dll in C:\xampp\php\ext